# Similar to "Generate n-grams from Pandas column while persisting another column" (unsolved), but with values

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram

I have some lines of text, and then their relevance weight.

```
Weight, Text
10, "I like apples"
20, "Someone needs apples"
```

Is it possible to get the combinations, keeping the values in the weights column? Something like:

```
weight, combinations
10, [I like]
10, [I apples]
10, [like apples]
20, [someone needs]
20, [someone apples]
20, [needs apples]
```

"Generate n-grams from Pandas column while persisting another column" (unsolved) is a similar question, but it is unsolved.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': [10, 20],
                   'Text': ["I like apples", "Someone needs apples"]})
df['Combinations'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x : list(combinations(x.split(), 2)))
df = df.explode('Combinations')
df.drop('Text', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Weight       Combinations
0      10          (I, like)
0      10        (I, apples)
0      10     (like, apples)
1      20   (Someone, needs)
1      20  (Someone, apples)
1      20    (needs, apples)
```

Answer (score 2):

Panda's explode() is a relatively new feature (.25) that enables an efficient solution like David M.'s.   It also addresses issues that previous typical solutions had when the list column was a list of lists.

Before explode() a typical solution would look like this:

```
someDF = pd.DataFrame({col:np.repeat(someListColDF[col].values,    
                      someListColDF[someListCol].str.len()) for col in someListColDF.columns.drop(someListCol)} ).assign(**{someListCol:np.concatenate(someListColDF[someListCol].values)})[someListColDF.columns]
```

But this doesn't seem to work when someListCol is a list of lists.

Here are the intermediate steps:

```
import itertools
someDF = pd.DataFrame([[10, "I like apples"],[20, "Someone needs apples"]], 
                     columns = ["Weight", "Text"])
```

Repeat the Weights the correct number of times

```
weightList = np.repeat(someDF["Weight"].values, someDF["Permute"].str.len())
```

Get all possible 2 element permutations (assuming order matters), and concatenate them into an array

```
someDF["Permute"] = someDF["Text"].apply(lambda x: list((itertools.permutations(x.split(),2))))
```

```
print(someDF["Permute"])

0    [(I, like), (I, apples), (like, I), (like, app...
1    [(Someone, needs), (Someone, apples), (needs, ...
```

```
permuteList = np.concatenate(someDF["Permute"].values)
print(permuteList)

array([['I', 'like'],
   ['I', 'apples'],
   ['like', 'I'],
   ['like', 'apples'],
   ['apples', 'I'],
   ['apples', 'like'],
   ['Someone', 'needs'],
   ['Someone', 'apples'],
   ['needs', 'Someone'],
   ['needs', 'apples'],
   ['apples', 'Someone'],
   ['apples', 'needs']], dtype='<U7')
```

But when I try to glue these together in normal ways by using, for example, np.column_stack(), np.vstack() and np.concatenate(axis=1), the list of lists keeps getting misinterpreted, and reshaping doesn't seem to help.

Ultimately I had to resort to this kludge:

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame(weightList, columns=["Weight"])
newDF["Permute"] = [i for i in permuteList]
```

Output

```
    Weight            Permute
0       10          [I, like]
1       10        [I, apples]
2       10          [like, I]
3       10     [like, apples]
4       10        [apples, I]
5       10     [apples, like]
6       20   [Someone, needs]
7       20  [Someone, apples]
8       20   [needs, Someone]
9       20    [needs, apples]
10      20  [apples, Someone]
11      20    [apples, needs]
```

All this is a roundabout way of saying Thank You to the Pandas developers for giving us explode()!